# Confusion with mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I currently have 3 tables Assessment, Question and QuestionOption. Each assessment has some questions and each question has some question options. Initially I started our with `@OneToMany` mappings for these but later one due to the fields that I have I had to had composite keys in Question so the entire mapping changed. I am not satisfied with the current state. Can someone help me in mapping the tables.

The main reason I had to do this was that while instering questions, I realised that question number can be the same across multiple assessments. So I made it a composite key with questionNumber+assessmentId. Also the same thought process with question option. where the same question options can exist along different questions. How can and avoid this and keep it simple.

Assessment

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"questionList"})
public class Assessment {

    @Id
    private String assessmentId;

    private String assessmentTopic;

    private String assessmentSubTopic;

    private String assessmentLevel;

    private String createdBy;

    private String rating;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "assessment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Question> questionList;
 //Getters and setters
}
```

Question

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"assessment"})
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name =  "assessmentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Assessment assessment;

    private String questionText;

    private String questionURL;

    private QuestionStatus questionStatus;

    //    private int questionNumber;
    private QuestionTypes questionType;
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

QuestionAssessmentKey- The composite key

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionAssessmentKey implements Serializable {

    private int questionNumber;

    private String assessmentId;
 //Getters and setters
}
```

QuestionOption

```
@Entity
public class QuestionOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int questionOptionId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="assessmentId", referencedColumnName = "assessmentId"),
            @JoinColumn(name="questionNumber", referencedColumnName = "questionNumber")
    })
    private Question question;

    private Character questionOption;

    private String questionOptionText;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Well, just use a technical, autogenerated ID for all entities, and make the question number a regular field of the question, like any other field.

Comment: @JBNizet is correct. In addition you can introduce a unique constraint around  the questionNumber and the assessmentId to enforce the data

Comment: So if I have quesitonNumber and assessmentId in Question and a separate questionAutoId which is a autogen id, then on which field should I have the onjetomany mapping to question option.

Comment: You shouldn't have assessmentId. You should have a ManyToOne association to make your OneToMany bidirectional, or nothing at all to leave it unidirectional. And associations should be mapped by the IDs. Read the Hibernate documentation, and see how OneToMany, unidirectional and bidirectional, are implemented.

Comment: So u basically mean that I should have `@OneManyList<Question>` in `Assessment` and `@ManyToOne Assessment` in `Question`. Similarly `@OneToMay List<QuestionOptions>` in `Question` and `@ManyToOne Question` in `QuestionOption`.